# How to reload a page using react router Link component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a component

```
export const NetworkStatus = ({ }) => (
     <div>
       <Link to="window.location.reload">Click here to refresh page</Link>
     </div>
  )
```

Here , I am trying to reload a page using the Link of react-router . But this seems to be not working. How to fix this ?

Comment: you're passing "window.location.reload" as a static string, you need to read the value of the variable, for that you pass the variable between curly braces {myVariable}
in your case window.location.reload is a method and not a variable, you call it with an event handler like onClick for example

Answer (score 0):

Use a button instead to reload the page:

```
export const NetworkStatus = ({ }) => (
     <div>
       <button onClick={_ => window.location.reload()}>Click here to refresh page</Button>
     </div>
  )
```

**Edit:**
If you want to handle the same using `Link` component, you can do so as:

```
<Link onClick={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.reload()
}}>Click here to refresh page</Link>
```

Comment: Yes I can use that.. But is there any way with the LInk

Answer (score 0):

you can mimik the behaviour of the Link component by adding a onClick property event handler to the Link component. Then either use the history api from React Router, or simply use the window.location.reload() api call. Either way you need to call a function for the expected behaviour.

```
// option 1 using history api from React router
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createHistory();
...
<Link onClick={() => history.go(0)}>Click here to refresh page</Link>

// option 2 use browser window api 
<Link onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>Click here to refresh page</Link>
```

Comment: Here, after using second approch it gives typo error 

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<LinkProps>): Link', gave the following error.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: LinkProps, context?: any): Link', gave the following error.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.ts(2769)

Comment: You are calling these methods during rendering rather than providing a callback that calls them when the link is clicked.